# Blazor - Server Side - Cookie Authentication

Tags: authentication, blazor, server-side

I want to implement the Authentication in Blazor Server Side, using the cookie Authentication, I have checked a lot of sample projects, but all of them are using Microsoft.Identity.

Comment: Using Identity is the easiest way to do it. you can customize it as you like for example if you use custom tables for user details and password, you can change Identity to use those tables and manually authenticate users. However if you can use Identity and replace your user accounts with Identity Aspnet Users table, you will also get many builtin things, like password reset, account confirmation, storing claims, etc.

Comment: @Umair could you please suggest a link to a resource where they explain how to do the Identity customization that you mentioned? Specially the custom tables customization. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with cookie auth and server-side Blazor, is that the web socket that server-side Blazor uses to talk to the server will remain open and connected long after the cookie expires. There might be a way to end/refresh this websocket periodically, but I didn't look into it.

If your actually using Blazor WebAssembly you have to implement your own `AuthenticationStateProvider` that manages your login/logout.

You'll also want to implement a /user/keepalive endpoint so that when a user navigates their cookie is kept alive. See Blazor's `NavigationManager.LocationChanged`

As well as a /user/me endpoint to detect if the cookie is still valid, and load any permissions when a user hits F5. Nothing more annoying than logging in, hitting F5 and having to login again.